# C# MVC Web application SQL not working properly

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller, mariadb, heidisql

Currently I am facing issue in my web application.

- Background > This web application is working well for 4 to 5 years

Recently, I receive the error message return as below.
(Noted: My Code never changes since 2 to 3 years ago)

`Unknown column ''' in 'where clause'`

Below is my query. And the query work well when running in HeidiSQL

`internal static readonly string GetTableSQL = @"  SELECT u.* FROM tableA u WHERE REPLACE(u.COLUMN_A,'\'','') IN (@CompanyCodes) "`

** @CompanyCodes will pass as parameters

I use **REPLACE** because COLUMN_A value has a single quote. That's why I want to replace it.

On 17-Feb-2023, my application start throw this error.
One strange thing is, when ever the error is throw, I restart my IIS and App pool, then the application work well for may be 30 min, after that the error throw again until I restart again my IIS service.

I do notice that on 16-Feb-2023, there is one window update  on .NET Framework 3.5, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows Embedded 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB5022733). But I am not sure does this error related to this window update.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/5022733

I do try different method of code such as

**Web application details:**

- DB - Mariadb (MySQL)
- Web C# MVC
- Hosting Server: Windows server 2012 R2
- IIS 8

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot or what is the root cause ?
Please help. Much appreciate!

Comment: I'm confused: `IN` takes a literal list of values, but `@CompanyCodes` only binds a single parameter value. Additionally, `REPLACE` should never be necessary for the server to compare two strings, even if one contains single quotes. Are you building your SQL query using string concatenation? (Or by using `string.Replace` to replace `@CompanyCodes`?) If so, that's the root cause of your problem; don't do that. Use proper SQL parameters instead.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger yes.. you are right. I am using string.Replace to replace the companyCodes. Which mean I have to change to the proper parameters instead right ? But I wonder why the error just appear recently ? As I am using the same code for few years.

Comment: I'm guessing the value of the string used to replace @CompanyCodes changed recently?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Unknown column ''' in 'where clause'` is happening because you're using string concatenation to build your SQL query.

Instead of doing this, you should use DbCommand parameters to pass the values. With a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Readme.md#list-support), this would look something like:

```cs
using var connection = GetYourConnection();
var companyCodes = new[] { "CODE1", "CODE2", ... };
var results = connection.Query<CompanyObject>(
    "SELECT u.* FROM tableA u WHERE u.COLUMN_A IN @companyCodes"
    new { companyCodes });
```